# How to load an external property file and load the values to another properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want load an external property file and set it values to another properties file, that is possible? e.g:

> C:\properties\file.properties
>
> id=userID
>
> password=pass
>
> ./main/resources/application.properties
>
> user.id=${id}
>
> user.password=${password}

I tray run this command, but it isn't working

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=C:/properties/file.properties  java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar


exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'id' in value "${id}"
```

Comment: `-D` args need to be specified before `-jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @PropertySource annotation from spring boot libraries. 
Documentation and examples: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html